# How to display a dictionary of Strings and Doubles in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to display a [String:[Double]] dictionary in a UITableView, but I'm getting a unexpected behavior when the doubles appears with different formats from original. Here is my basic code:

```
    var resdict = ["Joao":[55.5,43.8,88.5],"Carlos":[65.5,45.8,58.5],"Eduardo":[45.5,75.8,53.5]]

struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String
    var sectionObjects : [Double]
}
var objectArray = [Objects]()


    //table
@IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let name = objectArray[indexPath.row].sectionName
    let notas = objectArray[indexPath.row].sectionObjects

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1) \(name) -> \(notas)"

    return cell
}
```

And at viewDidLoad:

```
           for (key, value) in resdict {
        print("\(key) -> \(value)")
        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
    }
```

The results are:

1 Eduardo -> [45.5, 75.799999999999997, 53.5]

2 Joao -> [55.5, 43.799999999999997, 88.5]

3 Carlos -> [65.5, 45.799999999999997, 58.5]

I know I should apply maybe something like String(format: "%.2f", ...) but where and how?

Comment: Where do you add elements to this `objectArray`?

Comment: do you want to add the name and under it every grade in new line ?

Comment: Sorry, the elements are added in viewDidLoad() section as I edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you could use map and joined to convert your array of doubles to a string that starts with "[", has the values, separated with commas, and then ends with a "]"

Simpler, though, would be to change your line

```
let notas = objectArray[indexPath.row].sectionObjects
```

to

```
let notas = objectArray[indexPath.row]
  .sectionObjects
  .map { String(format: ,%.2f", $0) }
```

That would convert your array of doubles to an array of strings with 2 decimal places.

Then the expression "(notas)` will display the array of strings with opening and closing braces, and with comma delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add a computed property in `Objects` (actually singular `Object`) to map the `Double` array to `String` and join it comma separated.

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String
    var sectionObjects : [Double]

    var objectsStringRepresentation : String {
        return sectionObjects.map{String(format: "%.2f", $0)}.joined(separator:", ")
    }
}

...

let notas = objectArray[indexPath.row].objectsStringRepresentation
```

Comment: it worked too. I used the "joined separator" to better customize my table. Super thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1 you need to pass the data to object array,
2 use section to set the titles and the row for the grades

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
            resdict.forEach({(k,v) in
                objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: k, sectionObjects: v))
            })
            self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        var resdict = ["Joao":[55.5,43.8,88.5],"Carlos":[65.5,45.8,58.5],"Eduardo":[45.5,75.8,53.5]]

        struct Objects {
            var sectionName : String
            var sectionObjects : [Double]
        }
        var objectArray = [Objects]()


        //table
         func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return objectArray.count
        }
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
        }
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            let name = objectArray[section].sectionName
            return name
        }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
            let notas = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(notas)"

            return cell
        }
```